# Ошибка "'cirscr' was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
float km=10;
int main() 
{
    cirscr();
    int d;
    d=1;
    while (km<20)
    {
        km+=(km*0.5);
        d++;
    }
    printf ("Velosipedist byl v puti %d dnei",d);
    getch();
}
```

Такие ошибки появляются, когда пишешь: float a=b=c=20.1 'c' was not declared

Comment: Вам бы почитать учебник по C, какой угодно для начала.

Comment: VladD, эта маленькая программа из КУРСА, Интуит точка ру!!! Там просто так и написано в конце...

Comment: @Дато: я бы посоветовал всё же сесть за книгу, online-курсы могут оказаться профанацией.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ошибка в использовании функции

```
clrscr()
```

Вы ошиблись в имени функции когда писали) (см. выше)

Comment: Просто в стандартной библиотеке C нет функции cirscr()